# SyntaxError: Unexpected token O with every POST request, not parsing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using Angular and ES6 to send data to Spring Boot RESTful API.

```
class PostsService {
    constructor($http) {

        this.getAllPosts = () => {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/posts');
        };

        this.addPost = () => {
            let data = {content : "BBB", date : "55.55.5555"};
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/newPost', data);
        };
    }
}

PostsService.$inject = ['$http'];

export default angular
    .module('blog.Posts')
    .service('PostsService', PostsService);
```

GET request works without any problems.

POST totally sends the data (REST API gets it and puts it into the database as it should), on the other hand, generates this silly, and completely weird error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token O
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:1351:15)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:10202:17)
    at http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:10293:13
    at forEach (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:390:21)
    at transformData (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:10292:4)
    at transformResponse (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:11065:22)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:15621:29)
    at http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:15637:28
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:4000/build/bundle.js:16889:29)
```

I think it's worth to point out, that I'm using webpack, and no JSON parsing is done whatsoever (excluding angular http parsing, that I have no information of).

Comment: it sounds like the response on the server is not correct.

Comment: Please go into browser developer tools and copy the JSON from the response. It seems like your backend is not returning well-formatted json

Comment: Holy smokes, guys, thank you very much. I returned ArrayList instead of String from backend and everything begun to work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The thing was - it is somehow required, that backend returns JSON. So I changed:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/newPost", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody() String createPost(@RequestBody Post payload) {
        repository.save(payload);
        return "OK";
    }
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/newPost", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody() List<String> createPost(@RequestBody Post payload) {
        repository.save(payload);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("OK");
        return list;
    }
```

And it worked. Cheers doods!